# Install of graphite in centos-7 using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'm following below link when i try to run this (pip install graphite-web) its failing.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-graphite-on-centos-7

```
Collecting graphite-web
  Using cached graphite-web-1.0.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django<1.9.99,>=1.8 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from graphite-web)
Collecting django-tagging==0.4.3 (from graphite-web)
  Using cached django_tagging-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from graphite-web)
Collecting pyparsing (from graphite-web)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cairocffi (from graphite-web)
  Using cached cairocffi-0.8.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-EgudUq/cairocffi/setup.py", line 44, in <module>
        extras_require={'xcb': ['xcffib>=0.3.2']},
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 265, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 289, in fetch_build_eggs
        parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 618, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 862, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 874, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 339, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 653, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 849, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1130, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1118, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EgudUq/cairocffi/
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed by running 
pip install cairocffi==0.6

Comment: Strange, maybe some centos specific thing. Usually it should be fixed by installing `libffi` and `libffi-devel` packages using `yum install libffi libffi-devel`.